# Typescript: onChange Event Calculation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

How can I get the total ticket price, when I changed the number of persons?

html code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="person">Person</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="person" id="input" (change)="countPrice($event)">

        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="output" formControlName="price" (change)="countPrice($event)">>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

typescript code:

```
onDestination(eve) {
  this.http.post(environment.api_url + `/admin/get_price`, {

    "from_city": this.r.from_city.value,
    "to_city": this.r.to_city.value,

  }).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.price = data['data']['price'];
    console.log(this.price);
    this.bookingForm.patchValue({
      'price': this.price
    });
  })
}
countPrice(event) {

}
```

I want to display total price. By multiplying it with total amount of people. I don't know how to get the price from upper change event. Please someone help me solve this problem.

Comment: Try not post the entire page instead only post relevant parts to your problem, having such a large code posted for a small problem discourages people from even reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `valueChanges` could come to the rescue.

```
this.bookingForm.get('person').valueChanges.subscribe(num => this.countPrice(num));
```

Then, `countPrice()` could implement and return the calculation:

```
countPrice(totalPeople: number): number {
    return this.price * totalPeople;
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#managing-control-values

Comment: thank you sir, it's working fine for me. thanks once again